# Is it clear that $\epsilon_{abcd}F^{ab}(\delta^{\mu}_e\delta^{\nu}_f-\delta^{\mu}_f\delta^{\nu}_e)\eta^{ce}\eta^{df}$ vanishes?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

Is it clear that $$\epsilon_{abcd}F^{ab}(\delta^{\mu}_e\delta^{\nu}_f-\delta^{\mu}_f\delta^{\nu}_e)\eta^{ce}\eta^{df}$$ vanishes without computing explicitly?

Here $\epsilon_{abcd}$ is the totally antisymmetric tensor in 4 dimensions, $F^{ab}$ is the antisymmetric electrodynamics tensor, $\delta$s are the Kronecker deltas, and $\eta$s are the (symmetric, diagonal) Minkowski metrics.

One way to show this vanishes, for instance, would be to show that we are contracting an antisymmetric tensor with symmetric one. I don't think that's the case, however.

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really look like it is going to vanish. Everything after $\epsilon$ is asymmetric in $ab$ and $cd$.